# Как сделать проверку орфографии сразу нескольких языков?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, проверка-орфографии

Язык проверки орфографии такой какой язык раскладки клавиатуры был при запуске программы.

Так пытаюсь переключить. Переключение не происходит :

```
textEditor.ContextMenu.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("ru-RU");

textEditor.ContextMenu.SetResourceReference(Control.LanguageProperty, "ru-RU");
```

```
public class TextEditor : RichTextBox, ITextEditorComponent, IServiceProvider, IWeakEventListener 
{
```

XAML

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <SpellCheckFor:SpellCheckBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

SpellCheckBehavior

```
SpellCheckBehavior : Behavior<TextEditor>
    ...
    private TextEditor textEditor;
    textBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
    textBox.SetResourceReference(Control.LanguageProperty, "ru-RU");

    textEditor.ContextMenu.SetResourceReference(Control.LanguageProperty, "ru-RU");
    textEditor.ContextMenu.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("ru-RU");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня работает вот такой простой код:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="TB" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="ru-RU" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <Button Click="OnLanguageChange" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Switch to English</Button>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void OnLanguageChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => 
        TB.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-US");
}
```

[image: поменяли язык]

Исходя из [этого обсуждения](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06a2cc61-f2ae-4534-b35a-6c676bc2bcb2/c-wpf-multilingual-spellcheck-on-richtextbox?forum=wpf), на вашей системе могут быть не установлены нужные языковые пакеты. Если это так, их можно либо доустановить на машине пользователя, либо таскать с собой файлы со словарями и подгружать как [`CustomDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Вы каким тулзом гифки делаете такие красивые?

Comment: @alexolut: http://www.cockos.com/licecap/. Вроде работает :)

Comment: Работает `textBox.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("ru-RU");`
А можно как-то одновременно использовать два языка?

Comment: @codename0082016: Я не пробовал, но возможно, поучится несколько словарей обозвать, например, английским языком, и подключить? Интернет упорно молчит.